# How to disconnect the streaming on the exact date & time

Tags: python, twython

I am using Python and TwythonStreamer to stream statuses from Twitter. Currently, I setup a automatic disconnect by counting the number of collected tweets as below:

First I set this globally

```
max_tweets = 8000
```

Then in `def on_success(self, tweet)` , I have a code snippet:

```
if (count >= max_tweets):
  self.disconnect()
  return False
```

How can I disconnect the stream on exact date and time, let's say, on 'October 12, 2014 00:00:00'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the stream process acts like a `serverForever` server (unless you pass a retry count)

```
twython/streaming/api.py._request
if self.retry_count and (self.retry_count - retry_counter) > 0:
    time.sleep(self.retry_in)
    retry_counter += 1
    _send(retry_counter)
```

The only way to stop the process is, do a `self.shutdown` itself in `on_success` callback when some condition will be true 
OR,
 the hard way:  wrap the stream with a process, keep its pid or reference ,and kill it from another process (like is commented [here](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/issues/291))

**EDIT**: An approach of streamer wrapper and its caller

```
class Your_Streamer(TwythonStreamer, Process):
    def __init__(self, ):
        Process.__init__(self)
        consumer_key, consumer_secret, oauth_token,oauth_secret = '','','','' #your twitter keys
        super(SocialVane_Streamer, self).__init__(consumer_key, consumer_secret, oauth_token,oauth_secret)
    def run (self):
        keyword_list =[] #the keywords you want to monitorize 
        if keyword_list:
            logger.info("start_monitoring, tracking keywords = %s" % ','.join(keyword_list))        
            self.statuses.filter(track=','.join(keyword_list))
    def on_error(self, status_code, data):
        print status_code
        # Want to stop trying to get data because of the error?
        # Uncomment the next line!
        # self.disconnect()                
    def on_success(self, data):
        if 'text' in data:
            pass #do what you need
```

And now from another thread, can be a `main` method or what you want

```
stream = Your_Streamer()
if stream.ready():
    stream.start()
    logger.debug("pid %i created" % stream.pid)
    while not your_stop_condition: 
        import time
        time.sleep(1000) #some sleep
    stream.terminate()
```

Comment: So what exactly should I do in this case? Implement a timer to stop the process?